# How to convert degree minute second to degree decimal

Tags: python, parsing, gis

I receive the latitude and longitude from GPS with this format:

Latitude : 78°55'44.29458"N

I need convert this data to:

latitude: 78.9288888889

I found this code here: [link](http://en.proft.me/2015/09/20/converting-latitude-and-longitude-decimal-values-p/)

```
import re

def dms2dd(degrees, minutes, seconds, direction):
    dd = float(degrees) + float(minutes)/60 + float(seconds)/(60*60);
    if direction == 'E' or direction == 'S':
        dd *= -1
    return dd;

def dd2dms(deg):
    d = int(deg)
    md = abs(deg - d) * 60
    m = int(md)
    sd = (md - m) * 60
    return [d, m, sd]

def parse_dms(dms):
    parts = re.split('[^\d\w]+', dms)
    lat = dms2dd(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3])
 
    return (lat)

dd = parse_dms("78°55'44.33324"N )

print(dd)
```

It is working for for this format

```
dd = parse_dms("78°55'44.33324'N" )
```

but it is not working for my datafromat. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the seconds 44.29458 are split at `.`.

You could either define the split characters directly (instead of where *not* to split):

```
>>> re.split('[°\'"]+', """78°55'44.29458"N""")
['78', '55', '44.29458', 'N']
```

or leave the regular expression as it is and merge parts 2 and 3:

```
dms2dd(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2] + "." + parts[3], parts[4])
```

---

**Update:**

Your method call `dd = parse_dms("78°55'44.33324"N )` is a syntax error. Add the closing `"` and escape the other one. Or use tripple quotes for the string definition:

```
parse_dms("""78°55'44.29458"N""")
```

Comment: It is still not working when I add the second option to the code

Comment: Um, if you call your function like `parse_dms("78°55'44.33324"N )` that's a syntax error. You need to pass the string like I did: `parse_dms("""78°55'44.29458"N""")`. Alternatively you can escape the quotes like `"78°55'44.29458\"N"` or `'78°55\'44.29458"N'`. For more details you should look into the syntax for defining strings in Python.

Comment: ahh okey Now I got it. Thanks Falko :)

Comment: If I have an array containing large number of such coordinates then how do I  convert by this function?

Answer (score 27):

Here's my one liner (fine, fine – maybe it's two lines) :)

```
import re
lat = '''51°36'9.18"N'''
deg, minutes, seconds, direction =  re.split('[°\'"]', lat)
(float(deg) + float(minutes)/60 + float(seconds)/(60*60)) * (-1 if direction in ['W', 'S'] else 1)
```

This outputs `51.60255`

Answer (score 16):

The function above `dms2dd` is incorrect.

Actual (With error):

```py
if direction == 'E' or direction == 'N':
        dd *= -1
```

Corrected Condition:

```
if direction == '**W**' or direction == '**S**':
        dd *= -1
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but for whoever is following along, just thought I'd point out that you seem to have incorrect logic in your `dms2dd()` function regarding the sign of your decimals. You have:

```
if direction == 'E' or direction == 'N':
    dd *= -1
```

But it should only be negative if the direction is West (W) of the Prime Meridian or South (S) of the equator. So it should rather be:

```
if direction == 'W' or direction == 'S':
    dd *= -1
```

Here's a quote from a thorough guide: https://www.ubergizmo.com/how-to/read-gps-coordinates/

> The coordinate for the line of latitude represents north of the
>   Equator because it is positive. If the number is negative, it
>   represents south of the Equator.
>
> [...] The coordinate for the line of longitude represents east of the
>   Prime Meridian because it is positive. If the number is negative, it
>   represents west of the Prime Meridian.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this module https://pypi.org/project/dms2dec/

## Convert DMS to Decimal.

## Usage

```
from dms2dec.dms_convert import dms2dec

dms2dec('''36°44'47.69"N''') # converts to dec
dms2dec('''3° 2'33.53"E''') # converts to dec
```

Answer (score 2):

I have slightly modified the re:

```
parts = re.split('[^\d\w\.]+', dms)
```

And as @Falko advised to make it work, you can either use double double quotes or escape your quotes characters

```
parse_dms("53°19\'51.8\"N")
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple coordinates, you can read them in using pandas. Formatting is important - there should not be any white spaces. White spaces can be removed using the replace function. The outputs can be easily saved as a text file or spreadsheet. I just printed them for validation and rounded the decimals locations out to 4.

```
### read input file
df = pd.read_excel('dms.xlsx')

n = len(df)

for i in range(n):
  Lat_d = round(parse_dms(df.Lat[i].replace(" ", "")),4)
  Long_d = round(parse_dms(df.Long[i].replace(" ", "")),4)
  print(Lat_d, Long_d)
```

Comment: parse_dms is javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`clean_lat_long()`](https://docs.dataprep.ai/user_guide/clean/clean_lat_long.html) from the library [DataPrep](https://dataprep.ai/) if your data is in a DataFrame. Install DataPrep with `pip install dataprep`.

```py
from dataprep.clean import clean_lat_long
df = pd.DataFrame({"Latitude": ["78°55'44.29458''N", "51°36'9.18''N"]})

df2 = clean_lat_long(df, lat_col="Latitude")
            Latitude  Latitude_clean
0  78°55'44.29458''N         78.9290
1      51°36'9.18''N         51.6026
```

Comment: This looked good but unfortunately when installing it with anaconda it wants to massively downgrade the pandas library, it seems it's not compatible with pandas 2

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `pygeodesy` which is useful for many other functions anyway, like finding mid-points of coordinates, accurate distance and bearing calculations.

```
from pygeodesy import parse3llh, fstr

x = parse3llh('000° 00′ 05.31″W, 51° 28′ 40.12″ N')
print (fstr(x, prec=6))
```

Result

```
51.477811, -0.001475, 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/medo-mi/dms-to-dd

```
import re

#Degrees Minutes Seconds to Decimal Degrees
def dms_dd(dd):
    dd = f"""{dd}"""
    dd = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9. ]', '', dd)
    dd = dd.split(" ")
    return round(float(dd[0])+(float(dd[1])/60)+(float(dd[2])/3600), 8)
```

Comment: Seems to ignore the N,S,E,W information