# Python Convert Degrees Minutes Seconds To Decimal

Tags: python, coordinates

I have some coordinates which are presented in degrees, minutes, and seconds;

like

```
'544441N,0253123E'
'544309N,0253808E' 
'543759N,0254153E'
'543516N,0253209E'
'543703N,0252603E' 
'544441N,0253123E'
```

I need to convert them to lat-long form with python.

Comment: I think this question cover the subject and you can get your answer from it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997361/how-to-convert-degree-minute-second-to-degree-decimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
def dms(s):
    r = []
    for d in s.split(','):
        dec = int(d[-3:-1]) / 3600 + int(d[-5:-3]) / 60 + int(d[:-5])
        r.append(f'{dec:.4f}{d[-1]}')
    return r


print(dms('544441N,0253123E'))
```

Note that this is not proposed as robust solution as it will fail if the input is in an unexpected format